# Issue with OR function in an Array

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

Here is my full formula:

{=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(Table1[Val/COArea Crcy]),Table1[Val/COArea Crcy],0)*IF(OR(Table1[Cost element name]="LABOR",Table1[Cost element name]="CONTRACTOR"),1,0)*IF(OR(Table1[Cost Element]="96500",Table1[Cost Element]="96510"),1,0)*IF(LEFT(Table1[Object],LEN($C$2))=$C$2,1,0))}

The part I'm having an issue with is this:

IF(OR(Table1[Cost element name]="LABOR",Table1[Cost element name]="CONTRACTOR"),1,0)

If I use just "labor" or "contractor", the formula will work.  However, combining with an OR function causes a problem.

For example: If(Table1[Cost element name]="Labor",1,0)    will work for labor and replacing with contractor will work for that one and the total will be correct.  I just don't understand why my OR function is pulling all categories rather than just the 2 I want.

-Thanks
Matt

Comment: Excel's logical operators do not work in array formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like was said Array function do not like logical operators, so use `+` for `OR` and `*` for `AND`.

```
=SUM(IF((ISNUMBER(Table1[Val/COArea Crcy]))*(((Table1[Cost element name]="LABOR")+(Table1[Cost element name]="CONTRACTOR"))>0)*(((Table1[Cost Element]="96500")+(Table1[Cost Element]="96510"))>0)*(LEFT(Table1[Object],LEN($C$2))=$C$2),Table1[Val/COArea Crcy]))
```

Remember this is an array formula so it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.